# Create a view in BigQuery that flattens a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery that shows data in the following structure:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|    Date    | Product | CostPrice | SalePrice |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 01/01/2018 | hat     |        10 |        20 |
| 01/01/2018 | shoe    |         5 |        12 |
| 01/02/2018 | hat     |        11 |        22 |
| 01/02/2018 | shoe    |         6 |        13 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to flatten (is that the correct terminology?) the data so that each row only has one metric. This obviously requires a column for MetricName to determine which of the metrics from the first table is being provided in each row.

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|    Date    | Product     | MetricName | MetricValue |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 01/01/2018 | hat         | CostPrice  |          10 |
| 01/01/2018 | hat         | SalePrice  |          20 |
| 01/01/2018 | shoe        | CostPrice  |           5 |
| 01/01/2018 | shoe        | SalePrice  |          12 |
| 01/02/2018 | hat         | CostPrice  |          11 |
| 01/02/2018 | hat         | SalePrice  |          22 |
| 01/02/2018 | shoe        | CostPrice  |           6 |
| 01/02/2018 | shoe        | SalePrice  |          13 |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

I am not sure how to construct an SQL query that would achieve this?

Thanks,

J.Ayo

Comment: Thanks for the edit Yogesh. How did you change the ASCII that quickly? Is there a tool that can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Date, Product, 'CostPrice' AS MetricName, CostPrice AS MetricValue
FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Product, 'SalePrice' AS MetricName, SalePrice AS MetricValue
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as  below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '01/01/2018' Date, 'hat' Product, 10 CostPrice, 20 SalePrice UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2018', 'shoe', 5, 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/02/2018', 'hat', 11, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/02/2018', 'shoe', 6, 13 
)
SELECT Date, Product, 'CostPrice' AS MetricName, CostPrice AS MetricValue
FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Product, 'SalePrice', SalePrice
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Another option to avoid using UNION ALL (as it requires some redundant code) is as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE, Product, MetricName, MetricValue
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT<MetricName STRING, MetricValue INT64>
  ('CostPrice', CostPrice), ('SalePrice', SalePrice)])
```